# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Connected React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

When this code is run.  If I comment out:

`const tabs = this.getTabs(breakpoints, panels, selectedTab);`

the error goes away.  I have even commented out other `setState()` calls to try and narrow down where the problem was at.

Code (removed the extra functions):

```
export default class SearchTabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      filters: null,
      filter: null,
      isDropdownOpen: false,
      selectedFilter: null,
    };

    this.getTabs = this.getTabs.bind(this);
    this.tabChanged = this.tabChanged.bind(this);
    this.setSelectedFilter = this.setSelectedFilter.bind(this);

    this.closeDropdown = this.closeDropdown.bind(this);
    this.openDropdown = this.openDropdown.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { panels } = this.props;
    if (!panels || !panels.members || panels.members.length === 0) {
      this.props.fetchSearch();
    }
  }


  getTabs(breakpoints, panels, selectedTab) {
    const tabs = panels.member.map((panel, idx) => {
      const { id: panelId, headline } = panel;
      const url = getHeaderLogo(panel, 50);
      const item = url ? <img src={url} alt={headline} /> : headline;

      const classname = classNames([
        searchResultsTheme.tabItem,
        (idx === selectedTab) ? searchResultsTheme.active : null,
      ]);

      this.setState({ filter: this.renderFilters(
        panel,
        breakpoints,
        this.setSelectedFilter,
        this.state.selectedFilter,
        this.state.isDropdownOpen,
      ) || null });

      return (
        <TabItem
          key={panelId}
          classname={`${classname} search-tab`}
          headline={headline}
          idx={idx}
          content={item}
          onclick={this.tabChanged(idx, headline)}
        />
      );
    });

    return tabs;
  }

  render() {
    const { panels, selectedTab } = this.props;

    if (!panels || panels.length === 0) return null;

    const tabs = this.getTabs(breakpoints, panels, selectedTab);

    return (
      <div className={searchResultsTheme.filters}>
        <ul className={`${searchResultsTheme.tabs} ft-search-tabs`}>{tabs}</ul>
        <div className={searchResultsTheme.dropdown}>{this.state.filter}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const TabItem = ({ classname, content, onclick, key }) => (
  <li key={key} className={`${classname} tab-item`} onClick={onclick} >{content}</li>
);
```

Comment: You're calling ```setState``` potentially twice in ```componentWillUpdate```, which is [not allowed](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) according to the docs. You're also calling ```setState``` in 3 different places every time you try to render your component. Every time you call ```setState```, your component will rerender. That's going to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Christ, yea, I'm refactoring this code right now, it's a mess.  And that's the kind of issues I come across during refactoring I find the bad practices done and they cause me pain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of this loop:

```
  render  ----->   getTabs  ----->  setState -----
    ^                                            |
    |                                            |
    |____________________________________________v
```

You are calling getTabs method from render, and doing `setState` inside that, `setState` will trigger re-rendering, again getTabs ..... **Infinite loop**.

Remove `setState` from `getTabs` method, it will work.

Another issue is here:

```
onclick={this.tabChanged(idx, headline)}
```

We need to assign a function to onClick event, we don't need to call it, but here you are calling that method, use this:

```
onclick={() => this.tabChanged(idx, headline)}
```

Comment: that's not it, I've tried commenting out setState in getTabs, doesn't make a difference

Comment: I commented out <TabItem /> and it went away...hmmm

Comment: crap it's the tabChanged, that method calls setState

Comment: correct, that was not the only issue, check the updated answer :)

Comment: yea, read your whole reply, took out the method call and just put the ref

Comment: so is it ok that method calls made inside getTabs, those methods that live elsewhere, it's ok if they setState()?

Comment: nope, because you are calling a function from render that is doing setState,  if you are doing setstate in parent then it will re-render the child also (not in case when using PureComponent or using shouldComponentupdate for optimisation) it will also create a infinite loop.

Comment: so it's just bad practice period to be doing setState in render()

Comment: code will not work if we do setState in render, all the time it will throw the error : "Maximum call stack size exceeded" :)

Comment: also wondering where I could move that call to getTabs to if I want it out of render.  This component produces tabs it's SearchTabs but not sure where I should place the getTabs call that iterates panels to create tabs

Comment: you can call that function and return the TabItems also, but don't do setState, rearrange the code and do setState somewhere else like in componentDidMount lifecycle method or inside any event.

Comment: appreciate your help, you saved me some hair.  Ya the problem is that getTabs needs to call this.setFilter(panel, idx, selectedTab); because it determines the current filter based on each panel.  I'll have to see if I can pull that apart but it's not an easy seam

Comment: ha ESLint says not to call setState in componentDidMount

Comment: in that case do it in [componentWillMount](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/684#issuecomment-264094930), you can disable that also if you want, check this [how to disable](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md)