# react-dom: Incrementally change opacity of an element on click

Tags: reactjs, opacity

I'd like to be able to **increase opacity of a DOM element on click of a button**.

Wrapping my head around React's concepts, I think this should be done through using `state` and a functional `setState()` function.

However, I keep running into an error with the following code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ThoughtfulThoughts extends Component {

  state = {
    opacity: 0.4,
    thoughts:
      [
        "live and let leave",
        "just pee yourself",
        "who knows what 'laf' is?"
      ]
  }

  makeAppear = () => {
    // TODO: this causes a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      opacity: prevState.opacity + 0.2
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="thoughtful-thoughts">
        <div className="current-thought" style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
          {this.state.thoughts.map((thought, i) => (<p>{thought}</p>))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.makeAppear()}>Think for me</button>
      </div>
    )

  }
}

export default ThoughtfulThoughts
```

I **don't** want to [use jQuery](https://medium.com/@shuvohabib/using-jquery-in-react-component-the-refs-way-969de9aa651f), nor [direct DOM manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), nor 
[CSS transitions](https://medium.com/@joethedave/achieving-ui-animations-with-react-the-right-way-562fa8a91935), but would like to do this just in JS in "the React way".

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change `onClick={this.makeAppear()}` into `onClick={this.makeAppear}`

Comment: ^ What Chris said. To expand upon it, the reason your stack size is exceeded is because every time you render, you're calling that function `onClick={this.makeAppear()}`. And that function changes the state, which causes a re-render. This re-render calls that function, which changes the state--and so on. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: also you need to wrap `{
      opacity: prevState.opacity + 0.2
    }` by `()` otherwise use return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum call stack size exceeded - Connected React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823050/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-connected-react-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of minor issues in your code:

1. On your button component, change `onClick={this.makeAppear()}` into `onClick={this.makeAppear}`.
2. Nicely done on using the function approach instead of the object approach for updating a state variable based on a previous state variable. However, you have a minor syntax. Either do:

   ```
   this.setState(prevState => (
     {opacity: prevState.opacity + 0.2}
   ));
   ```

   or

   ```
   this.setState(prevState => {
     return {opacity: prevState.opacity + 0.2}
   });
   ```

   whichever you prefer.
3. Add a `key` property to each item you return from your `map()`: So basically:

   ```
   {this.state.thoughts.map((thought, i) => (<p key={i}>{thought}</p>))}
   ```

   You can probably use `i` safely as the key here because the order of the items in  `thoughts` array will remain static. For more info about keys and how to use them properly, take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905).

---

**Demo:**

```js
class ThoughtfulThoughts extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      opacity: 0.4,
      thoughts:
        [
          "live and let leave",
          "just pee yourself",
          "who knows what 'laf' is?"
        ]
    }
  }

  makeAppear = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({opacity: prevState.opacity + 0.2})
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="thoughtful-thoughts">
        <div className="current-thought" style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
          {this.state.thoughts.map((thought, i) => <p key={i}>{thought}</p>)}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.makeAppear}>Think for me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ThoughtfulThoughts />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```